# Searching if an element exist in a queue c++

Tags: c++, search, queue

So I've been trying to search if a number entered by user does exist in the queue or not, if it does then the function will return true,otherwise false. However it didn't work no matter what method I try:

```
  bool cqueue::search(int x){ //this is my class cqueue
        if(empty()) { cout<<"\n\n queue is empty\n";  }
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
         if(array[i]==x){
             return true; cout<<x<<" is in the queue \n"; break; }
             else {
            return false; cout<<x<<" is not in the queue \n"; } 
         }
    }
```

Comment: Follow through your logic. What happens if the first element does not match your search?

Comment: Also if your queue is empty you don't return anything. Make sure you return something.

Answer (score 0):

Only your first cout statement might get executed, the others won't get executed because when you return something, that is the end of the function. Maybe move the cout statements before the return and it should work.

Also, you shouldn't return false if array[i] != x, that only means that array[i] is not the item you are looking for. Maybe you could add a boolean variable isFound and only set it to true if you found the value. If you get to the end of the loop, and you didn't find the value (isFound == false), then return false.

Comment: Thank you so much it finally worked and I understood the problem. I would like to ask, how can I know if the function returned true or returned false since it doesn't appear in the output "I mean when you run the code". Sorry I am a beginner and I would like to fully understand the operation.

Comment: In your main function you could have a statement like cout << search(x); If the value you see is 0, it means false, and if you see 1, that means true. But you could also have an if statement like this: if(search(x)) {cout << "Item found";} else {cout << "Item not found";} This would work because search is a function that returns a boolean value, so search(x) will evaluate to true, and execute the if part, or false, and execute the else part.

Answer (score 0):

You should improve your indentation to see the flow of the program.
Also you should know that anything after a return statement will not be executed since return "exits" the function. Like the others said if the check on the first element fails, the function exits with return false; Which means that no other checks will be done.

```
bool cqueue::search(int x)
{ //this is my class cqueue
    if(empty())
        cout<<"\n\n queue is empty\n";

    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        if(array[i]==x)
        {
            return true; 
            cout<<x<<" is in the queue \n"; 
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            return false; 
            cout<<x<<" is not in the queue \n";
        }
    }
}
```